# Ionic HttpClient GET works in browser, but doesn't work on device

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to do simple Get request to https server using proxy.conf.json

```
"/test": {
    "target": "https://192.168.1.10",
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
    }
```

It works in browser, but on device I get some kind of html code

```
this.http.get('/test', {responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(res => {
      console.log('res_',res);
      this.res1 = res;
    });
```

Comment: proxy.conf.json is not for production.

Comment: I'm using proxy for selfsigned ssl

Comment: what html code do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In capacitor.config.json add

```
  "server": {
    "cleartext": true
  },
```

so it look like:

```
{
  "appId": "com.app.ionic",
  "appName": "app",
  "bundledWebRuntime": false,
  "npmClient": "npm",
  "server": {
    "cleartext": true
  },
  "webDir": "www",
  "plugins": {
    "SplashScreen": {
      ...
    }
  },
  "cordova": {}
}
```